# How to get unique results with grep?

Tags: bash

The below mentioned scenario is a part of the logic that i want to implement as part of a jenkins job. I am trying to write a shell script.

I am using grep command to recursively search for a **particular string**. Sample result that grep returns is like this:

```
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test1.java: @Tags({ "B-05256" })
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test1.java: @MapToVO(storyID = "B-05256: prices in ST") 
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test1.java: @Tags({ "B-05256" })
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test2.java: @Tags({ "B-05256" })
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test2.java: @MapToVO(storyID = "B-05256:Lowest Price of the Season")    
./src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test2.java: @Tags({ "B-05256" })
```

I want to extract unique file paths such as:

```
/src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test1.java
/src/test/java/com/ABC/st/test/pricing/Test2.java
```

and then use each unique path in a maven command. So:

1. How can i extract unique file paths from the result set given by grep command?
2. How do i run a loop kind of a thing, where in every iteration i execute mvn command with unique file path?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I have used this command to extract all unique file paths:      find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec grep -il 'stella-env-upgrade' {} \;    Now i want to execute a maven command on each file path. How do i do it.?

Comment: Select one of the answers on here as the correct answer and then ask a follow up question if you still need more help. But the answer to your question is likely going to involve using `xargs`. Also you can probable just use `grep` and not need to involve `find` here at all with the `-r` and `--include` flags to `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need only the name of the matching files, `grep` has a command line switch for this:

```
-l, --files-with-matches
       Suppress  normal  output; instead print the name of each input file from which output
       would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is
       specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now how do i execute command on that file name. Ex- how do i pass that filename to a maven command. i am very new to shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your text into

```
sed 's/:.*//' | sort -u | while read path
do
    echo now execute your command using "$path"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `-l` flag to `grep` is for.

> -l, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match. (-l is specified by POSIX.)